# Attempting to compress data using zlib.h utility function compress, always returns Z_BUF_ERROR

Tags: c++, ubuntu-12.04, zlib, compression

According to the zlib manual this error indicates "not enough room in the output buffer". Below is my very basic compression routine. I have also confirmed that nUncompressedBuffer is being populated correctly. Also you will note that nCompressedBuffer is much larger than nUncompressedBuffer and no combination of buffer sizes is working for me. Help please :)

```
CDataBlock* CCompressionManager::Compress2(CDataBlock* pInBlock)
{
    U8     nCompressedBuffer[100000];
    U8     nUncompressedBuffer[1000];
    S8     status                 = 0;
    uLongf compressedBufferLength = 0;

    pInBlock->GetData()->GetData( nUncompressedBuffer, 1000 );

    status = compress2( nCompressedBuffer,
                       &compressedBufferLength,
                       nUncompressedBuffer,
                       pInBlock->GetData()->GetLength(),
                       Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION );

printf("status is: %i\n", status);
//this always results in -5 Z_BUF_ERROR


}
```

Comment: Well, you tell it the output buffer is 0 bytes long...

Comment: @PlasmaHH Iyiyi!!! You Sir are the man. I mean, thank you.

Comment: The first commenter should turn that comment into an answer.  It is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should tell it the output buffer is 0 bytes long.

– [@PlasmaHH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359916/attempting-to-compress-data-using-zlib-h-utility-function-compress-always-retur#comment26955681_18359916)